# Matlab, changin x-axis to date on colormap

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Im trying to make a space time plot using a colormap in Matlab. On the x-axis I want time in the format 'HH:mm'. The problem is that either the plot is visible with incorrect x-axis, or the plot disappears

```
numberOfCells = 50;
numberOfTimeSteps = 120;

for i = 1:numberOfCells
    for j = 1:numberOfTimeSteps
        temp(i,j) = rand*10;
    end
end
% to use this function, the array temp needs to be an array of           size[rows=numberOfcells, columns=numberOfTimesteps]
% make the startTime and endTime to the strings
startTimeString = '2013-03-21 08:00:00';
endTimeString = '2013-03-21 10:00:00';

formatOut = 'HH:MM';
% convert startTimeString and endTimeString into serial date number
startTimeNum = datenum(datestr(startTimeString,formatOut));
endTimeNum = datenum(datestr(endTimeString,formatOut));

xData = linspace(startTimeNum,endTimeNum,numberOfTimeSteps/30 + 1);

% load the colormap from mycmap.mat 
figure(1)
imagesc(temp);
colormap;
colorbar;
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = xData;
datetick('x',formatOut,'keepticks')
```

Comment: It might be helpful to actually provide complete copy&paste-ready code, without external dependencies. I don't have `mycmap.mat` and don't want to guess how to call your function. That said, why do you have `handle(gca)`? Simply saying `ax = gca;` would be more standard.

Comment: About the handle(gca) is needed in Matlab2014a or earlier, that is why this is used. School computer.

Comment: `set(gca,'XTick',xData)`?

Comment: Tried to add this code at the bottom, the x-axis is still not there, only the colormap. Should I remove something when i use this set(gca, 'XTick', xData)

Comment: The important part of my first comment was “please provide some copy&paste-able code.” I don't think you'll get a lot of help without that. That `set` command was just an aside suggestion you might or might not want to use instead of the two lines containing `ax`.

Comment: The Code is now executable, thank you for your patience, I am kind of new around here. @Christopher Creutzig

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to set your axes directly when calling imagesc as

`imagesc(xData, 1:50, temp);`

You can then call datetick with no problems. The underlying problem is that images (as created by imagesc) interact a bit weirdly with figures and their associated axis in matlab. You can make the axis display the correct number by setting 'XTickLabel', rather than 'Xtick'. But when I try and convert it to a date this way they all appear as time 00:00 for some reason, which I don't understand.